# How to backup etcd on a Kubernetes cluster created with kubeadm - rpc error: code = 13

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, kubeadm

I have a K8s cluster created with kubeadm that consists of a master node and two workers.

I am following this documentation article regarding the etcd backup: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#backing-up-an-etcd-cluster

I have to use etcdctl to backup the etcd db so I sh into the etcd pod running on the master node to do it from there: `kubectl exec -it -n kube-system etcd-ip-x-x-x-x sh`

NOTE: The master node hosts the etcd database in this path `/var/lib/etcd` which is mounted on the pod as a VolumeMount in `/var/lib/etcd`.

Following the doc I run: `ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints 127.0.0.1:2379 snapshot save snapshotdb` and it returns the following error:

```
Error:  rpc error: code = 13 desc = transport: write tcp 127.0.0.1:44464->127.0.0.1:2379: write: connection reset by peer
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to make it work adding the certificates info to the command:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints https://127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key snapshot save ./snapshot.db
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the Etcd configuration file in the following line on a node that Etcd is running.

/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml

After getting the command in the command section of the Etcd configuration,

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints https://127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key
```

you can run Etcd commands like below commands.

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints https://127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key member list
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints https://127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key snapshot save ./snapshot.db  
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints https://127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key snapshot status ./snapshot.db
```